# How to make a new column for days of the week

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, dayofweek

I am working with a FitBit daily activity dataset within BigQuery. I have a date column (stored as a date type), and I'm trying to make a new column that will reflect the days of the week (Saturday, Sunday, etc) alongside the original date column. I'm still fairly new to SQL, so I'm not sure how to do this. This is what I've tried:
[Attempt #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEPaT.png). I also tried to use the DATENAME function, but I kept getting an error message. Anyone who can point me in the right direction will be much appreciated!

Comment: what error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select ActivityDate, 
  format_date('%A', ActivityDate) as day_of_week
from your_table
```

with output like

[image]